# is it possible to maintain the different schema in same entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have two schema(claim and policy). For both schema am using same Entity class.
My problem is, claim schema has column city but policy schema does have city column. So If I use entity class by policy schema I get error. 
is this only the way to change the Entity class for each schema ? or is it possible to maintain the different schema in same entity class?

My Entity class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table_name")
public class X {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "xxx")
   private int xxx;

   @Column(name = "yyy")
   private String yyy;

   @Column(name = "city")
   private String city;      // only claim schema 
 }
```

I get the schema like this,

```
if(id.startsWith("SW")){
                session = getSWSession();
}
if(id.startsWith("HW")){
                session = getHWSession();
}
```

Comment: If a given Entity class is associated with 2 different tables, then how would Hibernate know to which table to flush?

Comment: Two table names are the  same only but the schema is different.

Comment: You may use inheritance and give different schema to different entities by using @Table(schema = "Schema1") annotation. In this way, you can use different columns for different schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two different mappings for different schema, so you have to create two java mapping classes and annotate them with the Table annotation to mark the [schema](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#schema%28%29) for each specific entity.